# Error in xi[[j]] : subscript out of bounds In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Tags: r, json, rstudio

I'm just trying to do something very simple and I am trying to do this in R.

```
install.packages("jsonlite")
install.packages("rjson")

library(jsonlite)
library(rjson)

dir <- ("D:\\bike")

file_list <- list.files(dir)
file_list

data <- data.frame()

for(file in file_list) {
  print(file)
  temp <- read_json(paste(dir, file, sep="\\"), header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  data <- rbind(data,temp)
}

str(data)
```

the error i get is

Error in xi[[j]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Eventually you can use `setwd("D:/bike")`

Comment: Also, are you sure that each JSON file you are opening have the same number of columns before binding them together in a single dataframe ?